# Is there a way to make the windows open new windows on taskbar first rather than last

Tags: windows, taskbar

I have a lot of software programs pinned to taskbar. So everytime I open a new window, its icon on the taskbar is at last after all my pinned shortcuts. So I need to scroll down everytime on taskbar to switch between the open pinned windows and open unpinned windows.

I wish all the new unpinned windows opened at the beginning of the taskbar following the pinned shortcuts. Is there any way to achieve this?

[image: My Computer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, As far as I know, no, there is no simple way to do that. But if you really need to achieve something like that I may help you somehow alternatively. Actually you can use keyboard-shortcuts to go to the taskbar elements directly.

You can use `(windows-key + #)` [Replace hash `(#)` with any number between 1 to 0 to directly access 1 to 10th positioned element of the taskbar directly]. Unfortunately we can't access any icon positioned above 10 position. But in your case you can access the last element of taskbar directly. To do that At first press `(windows-key + T)` , now press the `End` button which will take you to the last element in your taskbar.

Hope this helps a bit.